# How do the STL *-traits classes work?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, interface, stl

Templated classes like allocator_traits, iterator_traits, and (I think) type_traits, seem to behave like compile-time interfaces for other classes to implement, except that they can have default implementations.  This seems like an extremely handy feature to have, but I can't find any tutorials or generic documentation for how to implement this design pattern.  How do they work?  How can I write such a class?

Comment: [Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) and [template specializations](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Comment: I'm aware of what templates are.  Neither of those two sources are in-depth enough to cover how one would re-implement the "allocator_traits" class.  For instance, allocator_traits includes a type called const_pointer which by definition is Alloc::const_pointer if present, otherwise std::pointer_traits<pointer>::rebind<const value_type> according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits.  How can I have a type which refers to one thing if it's present, but defaults to another like that?

Comment: You should have been more specific. For something like that I think they would have to use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). That's what I think but I would wait for someone more knowledgeable to come around.

Comment: As it stands, this question is too open-ended. "How do they work?" - well, it's C++. Could you please try to narrow the scope of the question, and you'll surely get a great answer. :)

Comment: The truth is I'm looking for a reference or book or tutorial that explains C++ template programming in much more depth than what I've found so far.  The STL shows that there's a lot you can do with templates, but I can't find anything that goes beyond the basics.  Certainly I hadn't heard of SFINAE until 0x499's comment just now.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://itee.uq.edu.au/~conrad/misc/sanderson_templates_lecture_uqcomp7305.pdf&sa=U&ei=TWW3Uqi1FIvg2wXhioFY&ved=0CAsQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGbUYQkRb8ANe99g8Qrrx5QB9D0jw to start.  I am not aware of a single book or source that can teach the current burning edge of C++.